# How does one make wiktionary parser results more accessible, or make order with a chaotic list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, parsing, web-scraping

I've been using wiktionary parser to try and create a program that can search for words and get their definitions directly on wiktionary. The issue is that module just returns a ton of information that I have difficulty putting order in.

I've tried splitting the list, or doing "for" loops, replacing commas with `\n`'s, and searching up ways to make order in this chaotic mess, but I don't manage to.

Somebody posted a similar question, and received a "this parser generates a complicated structure of lists, dictionaries, etc, just get used to it lol" and it's unhelpful to the highest extent, so anything more constructive would be greatly appreciated

```py
from wiktionaryparser import WiktionaryParser
parser = WiktionaryParser()

fetchword = parser.fetch("exemple", "french")
print(fetchword)

>>> {'partOfSpeech': 'noun', 'text': ['exemple\xa0m (plural exemples)', 'example'], 'relatedWords': [], 'examples': []}

# result : so at this point it doesn't look that bad.
# ...but it's significantly worse in russian or in english:

fetchword = parser.fetch("человек", "russian")
print(fetchword)

>>>[{'etymology': 'Inherited from Old East Slavic человѣкъ (čelověkŭ), from Proto-Slavic *čьlověkъ, *čelověkъ.\n', 'definitions': [{'partOfSpeech': 'noun', 'text': ['челове́к • (čelovék)\xa0m\xa0anim (genitive челове́ка, nominative plural лю́ди or челове́ки*, genitive plural люде́й or челове́к* or челове́ков*, related adjective челове́ческий or челове́чий or людско́й, diminutive челове́чек, augmentative челове́чище, pejorative челове́чишко) (* Nominative plural - rare, poetic, other cases of челове́к in plural are used with numbers.)', 'person, human being, man', '(collective, singular only) mankind, man, the human race', 'also plural when used with cardinal words:'], 'relatedWords': [], 'examples': ['Отгово́рка-то кака́я капита́льная: „уж тако́й, де́скать, делово́й челове́к Пётр Петро́вич, тако́й делово́й челове́к, что и жени́ться-то ина́че не мо́жет, как на почто́вых, чуть не на желез́ной доро́ге“.Otgovórka-to kakája kapitálʹnaja: „už takój, déskatʹ, delovój čelovék Pjótr Petróvič, takój delovój čelovék, što i ženítʹsja-to ináče ne móžet, kak na počtóvyx, čutʹ ne na želeźnoj doróge“.A magnificent excuse: "Pyotr Petrovitch is such a busy man that even his wedding has to be done post-haste, almost by express."', 'Otgovórka-to kakája kapitálʹnaja: „už takój, déskatʹ, delovój čelovék Pjótr Petróvič, takój delovój čelovék, što i ženítʹsja-to ináče ne móžet, kak na počtóvyx, čutʹ ne na želeźnoj doróge“.', 'A magnificent excuse: "Pyotr Petrovitch is such a busy man that even his wedding has to be done post-haste, almost by express."', 'оди́н челове́к ― odín čelovék ― one person', 'два челове́ка ― dva čelovéka ― two persons, people', 'пять челове́к ― pjatʹ čelovék ― five persons, people', 'де́сять челове́к ― désjatʹ čelovék ― ten persons, people', 'два́дцать челове́к ― dvádcatʹ čelovék ― twenty persons, people', 'два́дцать оди́н челове́к ― dvádcatʹ odín čelovék ― twenty-one persons, people', 'два́дцать два челове́ка ― dvádcatʹ dva čelovéka ― twenty-two persons, people']}], 'pronunciations': {'text': ['IPA: [t͡ɕɪɫɐˈvʲek]'], 'audio': []}}]
```

Comment: What information are you trying to extract, exactly? (And please either link the earlier answer which you are criticizing, or remove the critique.)

Answer (score 0):

A good first step would be to use some function which reformats nested data structures (like JSON) to make them easier to read.

Standard Python comes with two useful functions, both of which I show below. There are various alternatives as well, both third-party Python libraries and external utilities like `jq`, which you could explore, but I'm just going to focus on the built-in options.

To prepare for the following examples, I first downloaded the definition of `человек`, as in your question:

```py
from wiktionaryparser import WiktionaryParser
wp = WiktionaryParser()

chelovek = wp.fetch('человек', 'russian')
```

Python's `json` module contains functions for downloading JSON and converting JSON representations into Python objects (lists and dictionaries), as well as the reverse: converting a Python object into a JSON representation. Here, I'll use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/json.html?highlight=json%20dumps#json.dumps) to convert the JSON object created by the Wiktionary parser into a readable string. Note that `json.dumps` just returns the formatted string. The Python command interpreter shows strings in the form in which they could be typed, which is useful but not very legible, so we need to use `print()` in order to see this formatted readably. `json.dumps` has a lot of options to customise the output format (see the documentation link above); here, I've used just two of them:

- `indent=2`, which inserts newlines and leading spaces to separates components into separate lines with appropriate indents to show nesting. (The default is to run everything together on a single line)
- `ensure_ascii=False`, which shows non-ASCII characters without conversion. (The default is to restrict the output to ASCII characters, using Unicode escape sequences for any other character)

```py
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(chelovek, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
[
  {
    "etymology": "Inherited from Old East Slavic человѣкъ (čelověkŭ), from Proto-Slavic *čьlověkъ, *čelověkъ.\n",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "text": [
          "челове́к • (čelovék) m anim (genitive челове́ка, nominative plural лю́ди or челове́ки*, genitive plural люде́й or челове́к* or челове́ков*, related adjective челове́ческий or челове́чий or людско́й, diminutive челове́чек, augmentative челове́чище, pejorative челове́чишко) (* Nominative plural - rare, poetic, other cases of челове́к in plural are used with numbers.)",
          "person, human being, man",
          "(collective, singular only) mankind, man, the human race",
          "also plural when used with cardinal words:"
        ],
        "relatedWords": [],
        "examples": [
          "Отгово́рка-то кака́я капита́льная: „уж тако́й, де́скать, делово́й челове́к Пётр Петро́вич, тако́й делово́й челове́к, что и жени́ться-то ина́че не мо́жет, как на почто́вых, чуть не на желез́ной доро́ге“.Otgovórka-to kakája kapitálʹnaja: „už takój, déskatʹ, delovój čelovék Pjótr Petróvič, takój delovój čelovék, što i ženítʹsja-to ináče ne móžet, kak na počtóvyx, čutʹ ne na želeźnoj doróge“.A magnificent excuse: \"Pyotr Petrovitch is such a busy man that even his wedding has to be done post-haste, almost by express.\"",
          "Otgovórka-to kakája kapitálʹnaja: „už takój, déskatʹ, delovój čelovék Pjótr Petróvič, takój delovój čelovék, što i ženítʹsja-to ináče ne móžet, kak na počtóvyx, čutʹ ne na želeźnoj doróge“.",
          "A magnificent excuse: \"Pyotr Petrovitch is such a busy man that even his wedding has to be done post-haste, almost by express.\"",
          "оди́н челове́к ― odín čelovék ― one person",
          "два челове́ка ― dva čelovéka ― two persons, people",
          "пять челове́к ― pjatʹ čelovék ― five persons, people",
          "де́сять челове́к ― désjatʹ čelovék ― ten persons, people",
          "два́дцать челове́к ― dvádcatʹ čelovék ― twenty persons, people",
          "два́дцать оди́н челове́к ― dvádcatʹ odín čelovék ― twenty-one persons, people",
          "два́дцать два челове́ка ― dvádcatʹ dva čelovéka ― twenty-two persons, people"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "pronunciations": {
      "text": [
        "IPA: [t͡ɕɪɫɐˈvʲek]"
      ],
      "audio": []
    }
  }
]
```

If you look carefully, you'll see that the text fields in that output are formatted as JSON strings; they are surrounded by double quotes and certain characters (such as newlines and internal double quotes) are escaped with backslashes. That's actually useful, because it makes the structure easier to understand. But don't get confused between that and the actual contents of the strings in the JSON object itself.

An alternative, which works for any nested data structure, is the `pprint` module. Again, [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint%20pprint#pprint.pprint) is useful since it the function has a lot of options. In this example, I've just used the defaults. Unlike `json.dumps`, `pprint.pprint` actually prints the formatted version on standard output. (There are other functions which can produce the formatted version as a string, if you want to write it out to a file.)

Example, using the same `chelovek`:

```py
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(chelovek)
[{'definitions': [{'examples': ['Отгово́рка-то кака́я капита́льная: „уж '
                                'тако́й, де́скать, делово́й челове́к Пётр '
                                'Петро́вич, тако́й делово́й челове́к, что и '
                                'жени́ться-то ина́че не мо́жет, как на '
                                'почто́вых, чуть не на желез́ной '
                                'доро́ге“.Otgovórka-to kakája kapitálʹnaja: '
                                '„už takój, déskatʹ, delovój čelovék Pjótr '
                                'Petróvič, takój delovój čelovék, što i '
                                'ženítʹsja-to ináče ne móžet, kak na počtóvyx, '
                                'čutʹ ne na želeźnoj doróge“.A magnificent '
                                'excuse: "Pyotr Petrovitch is such a busy man '
                                'that even his wedding has to be done '
                                'post-haste, almost by express."',
                                'Otgovórka-to kakája kapitálʹnaja: „už takój, '
                                'déskatʹ, delovój čelovék Pjótr Petróvič, '
                                'takój delovój čelovék, što i ženítʹsja-to '
                                'ináče ne móžet, kak na počtóvyx, čutʹ ne na '
                                'želeźnoj doróge“.',
                                'A magnificent excuse: "Pyotr Petrovitch is '
                                'such a busy man that even his wedding has to '
                                'be done post-haste, almost by express."',
                                'оди́н челове́к ― odín čelovék ― one person',
                                'два челове́ка ― dva čelovéka ― two persons, '
                                'people',
                                'пять челове́к ― pjatʹ čelovék ― five persons, '
                                'people',
                                'де́сять челове́к ― désjatʹ čelovék ― ten '
                                'persons, people',
                                'два́дцать челове́к ― dvádcatʹ čelovék ― '
                                'twenty persons, people',
                                'два́дцать оди́н челове́к ― dvádcatʹ odín '
                                'čelovék ― twenty-one persons, people',
                                'два́дцать два челове́ка ― dvádcatʹ dva '
                                'čelovéka ― twenty-two persons, people'],
                   'partOfSpeech': 'noun',
                   'relatedWords': [],
                   'text': ['челове́к • (čelovék)\xa0m\xa0anim (genitive '
                            'челове́ка, nominative plural лю́ди or челове́ки*, '
                            'genitive plural люде́й or челове́к* or '
                            'челове́ков*, related adjective челове́ческий or '
                            'челове́чий or людско́й, diminutive челове́чек, '
                            'augmentative челове́чище, pejorative '
                            'челове́чишко) (* Nominative plural - rare, '
                            'poetic, other cases of челове́к in plural are '
                            'used with numbers.)',
                            'person, human being, man',
                            '(collective, singular only) mankind, man, the '
                            'human race',
                            'also plural when used with cardinal words:']}],
  'etymology': 'Inherited from Old East Slavic человѣкъ (čelověkŭ), from '
               'Proto-Slavic *čьlověkъ, *čelověkъ.\n',
  'pronunciations': {'audio': [], 'text': ['IPA: [t͡ɕɪɫɐˈvʲek]']}}]
```

One thing to watch out for with `pprint` is that it avoids producing lines longer that the `width` option (default 80) by splitting long strings into consecutive quoted strings, which is valid in Python (so that `'Hello, ' 'world!'` is exactly the same single string as `'Hello, world!'`). In the case of lists of strings (which occur a lot in the Wiktionary data), you need to take care to notice whether or not there is a comma between two consecutive strings.